# biholomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am not sure how to proceed with this.
Let $A:= \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < |z| < 1, 0 < Arg(z) < \frac{\pi}{2} \} $

the question is to find a biholomorphic function f from $A$ to $\mathbb{D}$ where $\mathbb{D} := \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1 \}$

The only function I can think of is, $f: A \to \mathbb{D}, f(a):= a^4 $, then I almost geht the Unitdisc, but $ f(A)=\mathbb{D} \setminus [0,1) \neq \mathbb{D}$.

Is there any other way to obtain a biholomorphic function

Comment: The "usual strategy" for this type of problem is to build up a library of mutually-biholomorphic open sets with biholomorphisms between them, and then daisy-chain your way from each new set to a set in your library. Do you know any examples of this type (e.g., a disk to a half-plane, a quarter-plane to a half-plane...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\zeta=z^2$ mapps $A=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < |z| < 1, \,0 < \arg(z) < \frac{\pi}{2} \}$ to the semicircle $S=\{\zeta : |\zeta|<1, \Im \zeta>0\}$.
$\xi =\frac{1+\zeta}{1-\zeta}$ mapps $S$ 
to the first quadrant $Q=\{\xi : 0<\arg \xi<\frac{\pi}{2}\}$.
$\eta=\xi^2$ mapps $Q$ to the upper half-plain $H=\{\eta :\Im \eta>0\}$.
$w=\frac{i-\eta}{i+\eta}$ mapps $H$ to the unit disc $\mathbb{D} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1 \}$.
Compose all these functions, then we have
\begin{align}\xi&=\frac{1+z^2}{1-z^2},\\
\eta&=\left(\frac{1+\zeta}{1-\zeta}   \right)^2=\left(\frac{1+z^2}{1-z^2}   \right)^2,\\
w&=\frac{i-\eta}{i+\eta}=\frac{ i-\left(\frac{1+z^2}{1-z^2}   \right)^2}{
 i+ \left(\frac{1+z^2}{1-z^2}   \right)^2 }=i\,\frac{\,z^4+2iz^2+1\,}{z^4-2iz^2+1}.
\end{align}
Hence $f(z)=\displaystyle i\,\frac{\,z^4+2iz^2+1\,}{z^4-2iz^2+1}$ is a  biholomorphic function $ A \to \mathbb{D}$ we want.